# How to sort result of MongoDB query in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, database, nosql

I'm using MongoDB from Java and I've got this line to retrieve some data:

```
@Query("{'buyerId': ?0, 'status': ?1  }")
Page<CardOrder> getBuyerOrders(final String profileId, final Pageable pageable);
```

I'd like to sort them by the field 'created'.

```
{"created": 1}
```

How can I merge those two queries in the @Query annotation?

```
(i.e @Query("{'buyerId': ?0, 'status': ?1  }{"created": 1}"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post complete java code you are using, are doing it with JPA ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't wanna sound unpolite, but it's not necessary for this, I just need the query, no need for Java code.

Comment: this thing cant be managble in query as java have its own parser finally query been converted to native mongo query, sort parameter can be passed through java cod, so code is nessesory.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you can merge the two in the `@Query` annotation but you can make your repository method use a **[`Sort`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.9.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html)** parameter by adding it to the query method and dynamically pipe in **[`Sort`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.9.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html)** instances that will be applied to the query defined in `@Query`:

```
@Query("{ buyerId: ?0, status: ?1 }")
List<Thing> findThingsByUserIdAndStatus(String buyerId, String status, Sort sort);
```

Call the method:

```
repository.findThingsByUserIdAndStatus("foo", "ACTIVE", new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created"));
```

---

**-- UPDATE --**

To sort with Pageable, add the sort instance as a parameter to the Pageable object:

```
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(0, 1, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created"));
repository.getBuyerOrders("foo", request);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer; is that Sort the one coming from import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;?

Comment: Yes, it's from the [1.9.3 RELEASE](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.9.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html)

Comment: Thanks my friend, I'll try it and mark your solution as valid in a bit.

Comment: It's not letting me use it unfortunately, looks like Pageable and sort are incompatible: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method must not have Pageable *and* Sort parameter. Use sorting capabilities on Pageble instead! Offending method.  How can I sort with pageable?

Comment: I've made an update to the answer, you should be able to use the Pageable object with the sort as a parameter as above.